# Object to xml tag and format soap envelope in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap

I am new in Spring Boot application i face an issue with xml format to soap envelope like below detail:
I need to convert object from java class to xml and format xml tag to soap envelop like below:

Bookstore.java

```
package com.example.wsdltojavaclass.xmlrequest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "", namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
public class Bookstore {
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "bookList")
    @XmlElement(name = "book")
    private List < Book > bookList;
    private String name;
    private String location;

//    public void setBookList(List < Book > bookList) {
//        this.bookList = bookList;
//    }
//
//    public List < Book > getBooksList() {
//        return bookList;
//    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/xml")
    public void newroute() throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, JAXBException {
        List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        Bookstore bookstore = new Bookstore();
        bookstore.setName("Amazon Bookstore");
        bookstore.setLocation("Newyorkt");
        convertObjectToXML(bookstore);
        
        
    }

    private static void convertObjectToXML(Bookstore bookstore) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {       
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookstore.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(bookstore, System.out);
        m.marshal(bookstore, new File(BOOKSTORE_XML));
    }
```

And here is my result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2: xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <name>Amazon Bookstore</name>
    <location>Newyorkt</location>
</ns2:>
```

My expected result i need to change remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` and change format to

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:name>Amazon Bookstore</web:name>
      <web:location>Newyorkt</web:location>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So how to change from ns2 to soap envelope?